# How to add extra container port for singleuser in helm [Jupyterhub, multi notebook for users]

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

I am using the helm chart of jupyterhub.

https://github.com/jupyterhub/zero-to-jupyterhub-k8s/tree/main/jupyterhub

Instead of just only have port 8888, I want to add extra port for the "singleuser".

However, seem there are no way in the values.yaml for me to set that value.

Will any body have a good idea for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to allow users to host their own internal webservers/services? If so, you should check out [`jupyter-server-proxy`](https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyter-server-proxy) or [`jupyter-panel-proxy`](https://github.com/holoviz/jupyter-panel-proxy), both of which allow users to host a site at a "port" which gets served on the same domain, e.g. port 8787 on a jupyterhub served at `https://myhub.org` could be served at `https://myhub.org/hub/user-redirect/proxy/8787`.

For example, the [daskhub helm chart](https://github.com/dask/helm-chart/blob/main/daskhub/values.yaml#L55) uses the pangeo project's [pangeo docker image](https://github.com/pangeo-data/pangeo-docker-images/blob/master/pangeo-notebook/environment.yml#L46) which installs `jupyter-panel-proxy`:

from the pangeo-notebook's conda spec [`environment.yml`](https://github.com/pangeo-data/pangeo-docker-images/blob/master/pangeo-notebook/environment.yml#L46):

```yaml
name: pangeo
channels:
 - conda-forge
dependencies:
 # ... other packages
 - jupyter-panel-proxy
```

Comment: I just want to add port for remote spark worker to call. Since jupyter only can submit job in client mode, the notebook need to open port for spark driver.

Comment: Since the helm chart does not provide me to add port for notebook, so i can not cal the remote spark in jupyter

Comment: Take a look at how the dask helm chart is set up. It does something very similar, but uses these proxy services rather than opening a port directly.

Answer (score 0):

Add this entry to your `values.yaml` with the port you want in `PORT_NUMBER`

```
config:
  hub:    
    extraConfig:
      03-add-container-port.py: |
        from kubernetes import client
        def modify_pod_hook(spawner, pod):
            pod.spec.containers[0].ports.append(client.V1ContainerPort(PORT_NUMBER,name='jupyterlab',protocol='TCP'))
            return pod
        c.KubeSpawner.modify_pod_hook = modify_pod_hook
```